# Accessing real AngularJS service in Jasmine tests when mocked globally

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-runner

Let assume I have some service in AngularJS: `ComplexService`. It performs complex operations on init and has got a complex interface...

In Karma/Jasmine tests, to simplify other components unit tests, I have defined a mock **globally**<sup>[1]</sup> (outside of all `describe` declarations in Karma global scope):

```
beforeEach(function () {
    angular.mock.module('MYMODULE', function ($provide) {
        $provide.value('ComplexService', buildComplexServiceMock());
    });
});
```

<sup>[1](The reason of that decision was to avoid declaring it in each test suite again -we have about 50 of them and each eventually uses the service indirectly or by default)</sup>

Let now suppose, that I decided to Write some unit test for the complex service.

My question is: **Does it exist a way to access the real service now?** (not mock)

---

My temporary solution is to make my service accessible in global scope too and access it directly:

```
function ComplexService(Other, Dependencies) {
    //code here
}

angular.module('MYMODULE')
    .service('ComplexService', ['Other', 'Dependencies', ComplexService]);

window.ComplexService = ComplexService;
```

But I am not happy with it. (I don't want production code to be accessible globally, maybe except in tests)

Can somebody please, give me some clue?

### Edit

Another thing I would like to avoid if possible is specifying `ComplexService` dependencies in test directly (in a case the order would change in future)

Temporary solution which is **bad**:

```
let complexServiceTestable;

beforeEach(function () {
    inject(function (Other, Dependencies) {
        //If order of dependencies would change, I will have to modify following line:
        complexServiceTestable = window.ComplexService(Other, Dependencies);
    });
});
```

Something I would appreciate most if possible:

```
let complexServiceTestable;

beforeEach(function () {
    angular.mock.module('MYMODULE', function ($provide) {
        //some magic here
    });
});

beforeEach(function () {
    inject(function (ComplexService) {
        complexServiceTestable = ComplexService;
    });
});
```

Comment: I made method ~mock(params) and run it in each test file. Easy and clear)

Answer (score 1):

You could do is to explicity import the real `service` in your test and override the $provide mock with the real one:

```
import ComplexService from '../your-complex-service-path/ComplexService';

describe('....', function(){

  beforeEach(function () {
    angular.mock.module('MYMODULE', function ($provide) {
        $provide.value('ComplexService', ComplexService);
    });
  });

});
```

I understand the design decision but maybe the best thing would be to make a `factory` capable of injecting the `$provide` mocks of any Service passed as a parameter, name or path, It can be a little tricky but It might ended up being a more maintainable and descriptive approach.

Comment: Unfortunatelly I cannot use `import` in my project for many reasons. I will try to do some tricks with `factory` if would be easy enough. Thank you for answer anyway!

Comment: Then what you could do is on your first `beforEach` define 2 `$provide.value`statements, the first one will obtain the real service and use another name like: `$provide.value('ComplexServiceIntegrationTest', ComplexService);`and then use 
`$provide.value('ComplexService', MockedService);`
The on your test you can once more.. override the provided value:
`var ComplexService;
  inject(function($injector) {
    ComplexService = $injector.get('ComplexServiceIntegrationTest');
  });`
then:
 `$provide.value('ComplexService', ComplexService);`

Is super messy.. I don't recommend it

Comment: I just tried to do something very similar but got strange issues and side effects. I will try to do something about them tomorrow and I will give some feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @MatiasFernandesMartinez hints in comments, after some experiments I finally reached working solution (using provider):

In global Karma context:

```
beforeEach(function () {
    angular.mock.module('MYMODULE', function ($provide, ComplexServiceProvider) {
        $provide.value('ComplexServiceBackup', ComplexServiceProvider);
        $provide.value('ComplexService', buildComplexServiceMock());
    });
});
```

In ComplexService tests:

```
describe('ComplexService', function () {
    let complexServiceTestable;

    beforeEach(function () {
        inject(function (ComplexServiceBackup) {
            complexServiceTestable = ComplexServiceBackup.$get();
        });
    });
});
```